# Swift Compiler Error Issue after installing MapBoxNavigation using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mapbox

Xcode Version: 8.2
My Podfile:

```
target 'MapBoxOfflineSpike' do
  use_frameworks!
    pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.6'
    pod 'MapboxDirections.swift', '~> 0.10'
    pod 'MapboxNavigation', '~> 0.8.0'
end
```

I was trying to integrate this framework https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-ios into my project then I encountered errors below:
[image: xcode screenshot]

What would it take for me to be able to use this?

Answer (score 1):

Pod is installed successfully. So the problem isn't with Cocoapod. You've mentioned that you're using Xcode 8.2 and the error is about swift compiler issue. So I guess that you've to use the latest Xcode version.

**Solution:**

> use Xcode 8.3.3 (8E3004b)

I've tested both in Xcode 8.2 and Xcode 8.3.3 and it's working fine in Xcode 8.3.3.